# How can i change the padding o element by class name

Tags: javascript, css

im trying to change the padding of all the td in table.
somehow it doesnt work.
can you help ?

script ->

[image]

css ->

[image]

html ->

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `#curr-cell` is an ID. ID's are unique selectors, meaning it will only apply this style to the first instance of the ID. If you want the style to be applied to multiple cells, then you need a class selector. Another approach would be to select the table and select the children that are `td` elements. `.my-table-class td { /* style goes here */ }`.

Comment: Thanks martin!
if i want to apply the change in the script, what would i use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin said in the comments ID's are unique selectors, so for apply style for **td** tag in script, you can use some thing like this:

```
<script>
  let td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
  td[i].style.padding = "20px";
  }
</script>
```

or change Id to class: `strHtml += '<td class="curr-cell">'`

and use `document.getElementsByClassName('curr-cell')` in above code.